# React-native AwesomeProject buid failure

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am learning react-native from a Udemy course. I have followed the exact steps used by both my instructor as well as the RN documentation. However, I get 105 errors when I open in XCode (v6.4 on OSX 10.10.1). I tried targeting different builds, but to no avail. A few of the errors I get include

```
    Expected '>'
    Expected '}'
```

All the errors here seem to originate in the external files such as

```
    RCTVibration.m
    RCTAssert.h
    And so on.
```

The build tools I used are the ones recommended by fb.

```
    brew install node
    npm install -g react-native-cli
    react-native init AwesomeProject
    cd AwesomeProject
    react-native run-ios (Even tried opening it using Xcode in the finder)
```

On a side note, using Node v4.4.5, react-native cli 1.0.0, Homebrew 0.9.9.
Right up till I build the project, I encounter nothing unusual (Creating the project did take quite long and threw a few warnings at me.) Are there any dependencies I have failed to install? Help is appreciated!

EDIT: I either hadn't observed this before, or this appeared now. [Here's the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUqAH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React Native Getting Started prerequisites:

> Xcode 7.0 or higher. Open the App Store or go to https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/. This will also install git as well.

So you should update your XCode.